# Define a section in the ld default linker script and print its value

Tags: gcc, linker, ld, linker-scripts

I want to define a section in a linker script and take its value from the source code at runtime.

So far, I have taken the default `gcc linker` script file and I have added my section as following:

```
...
.my_section : { BYTE(0xAA); }
...
```

After compiling, I can see the section:

```
> gcc -T ls.ld main.c -o main
> objdump -h main
...
...
 27 .my_section   00000001  0000000000a01040  0000000000a01040  00001040  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 28 .comment      00000034  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00001041  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
```

Now, I want to print that value to `stdout` (and I'm expecting to obtain `0xAA`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

static volatile unsigned char SECTION __attribute__((section(".my_section")));

int main(){
    printf("hello %d\n", SECTION);
    return 0;
}
```

**The value I obtain is always 0. What I'm doing wrong?**

Comment: Not sure you can do what you want that way. You could try `#include <stdio.h>

extern unsigned char __my_section_addr[];

int main(){
    printf("hello %x\n", *(unsigned char *)(__my_section_addr));
    return 0;
}`  and in the linker script: `.my_section : { __my_section_addr = .; BYTE(0xAA); }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What I'm doing wrong?

You are forcing the linker to output in the program *two* sections, each called
`.my_section`.

One of them is caused by:

```
static volatile unsigned char SECTION __attribute__((section(".my_section")));
```

in `main.c`. In this `.my_section`, a symbol named `SECTION` is statically defined that
addresses a `char` that by default is statically initialized = 0. When you

```
printf("hello %d\n", SECTION)
```

you are of course printing the integer at that 0-initialized symbol.

The other `.my_section` is caused by the:

```
.my_section : { BYTE(0xAA); }
```

in `ls.ld`. This second `.my_section` begins with a byte = `0xAA` but is never
accessed by the program.

Here is an illustration. I have:

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

static volatile unsigned char MY_SECTION __attribute__((section(".my_section"))) = '!';

int main(){
    printf("hello %c\n", MY_SECTION);
    return 0;
}
```

and I have a linker-script `ls.ld` that is my `gcc` default linker script with:

```
.my_section : { BYTE(0xAA); }
```

appended last in `SECTIONS`.

Compile, link and run:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -T ls.ld -o prog main.c
$ ./prog
hello !
```

Look at the section details of `prog`:

```
$ readelf -t prog
There are 31 section headers, starting at offset 0x3990:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name
       Type              Address          Offset            Link
       Size              EntSize          Info              Align
       Flags
  ...
  [24] .my_section
       PROGBITS               PROGBITS         0000000000004010  0000000000003010  0
       0000000000000001 0000000000000000  0                 1
       [0000000000000003]: WRITE, ALLOC
  [25] .bss
       NOBITS                 NOBITS           0000000000004011  0000000000003011  0
       0000000000000007 0000000000000000  0                 1
       [0000000000000003]: WRITE, ALLOC
  [26] .comment
       PROGBITS               PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000000000003019  0
       0000000000000023 0000000000000001  0                 1
       [0000000000000030]: MERGE, STRINGS
  [27] .my_section
       PROGBITS               PROGBITS         0000000000006018  0000000000003018  0
       0000000000000001 0000000000000000  0                 1
       [0000000000000003]: WRITE, ALLOC
  ...
```

Section 24 is called `.my_section` and so is section 27. The local symbol `MY_SECTION`:

```
$ readelf -s prog | grep 'MY_SECTION'
37: 0000000000004010     1 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   24 MY_SECTION
```

is defined in section `24`.

Then look at the disassembly:

```
$ objdump --disassemble-all prog
prog:     file format elf64-x86-64
...
...
Disassembly of section .my_section:

0000000000004010 <__TMC_END__>:
    4010:   21                      .byte 0x21
...
...
Disassembly of section .my_section:

0000000000006018 <.my_section>:
    6018:   aa                      stos   %al,%es:(%rdi)
...
...
```

The first one, starting with `0x21` = `!`, is the one created in `main.c`
and accessed by the program. The second one, starting with `0xaa`, is
the one created by the linker script and not accessed by the program.

Choose one way of outputting your `.my_section` or the other:-

You can do it in your source code with:

```
static volatile unsigned char MY_SECTION __attribute__((section(".my_section"))) = 0xAA;
```

Or you can do it in the linker script as @MichaelPetch commented, like:

```
.my_section : { my_section_addr = .; BYTE(0xAA); }
```

and access the section in a program like:

```
$ cat main1.c
#include <stdio.h>

extern unsigned char my_section_addr[];

int main(){
    printf("section `.my_section` starts at %p and the 1st byte is %x\n",
            my_section_addr, (unsigned int)my_section_addr[0]);
    return 0;
}
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -T ls.ld -o prog main1.c
$ ./prog
section `.my_section` starts at 0x560a32964018 and the 1st byte is aa
```

But it is not actually necessary to customize the linker script in order to obtain the
address of a custom section in a program. See:

```
$ cat main2.c
#include <stdio.h>

static unsigned char pling __attribute__((section("my_section"))) = '!';
extern unsigned char __start_my_section;
extern unsigned char __stop_my_section;
static char * p_my_section_start = &__start_my_section;
static char * p_my_section_end = &__stop_my_section;

int main(){
    printf("section `my_section` starts at %p, ends at %p, and the 1st byte is %c\n",
            p_my_section_start, p_my_section_end, p_my_section_start[0]);
    return 0;
}

$ gcc -o prog main2.c
$ ./prog
section `my_section` starts at 0x55db7b0fb020, ends at 0x55db7b0fb021, and the 1st byte is !
```

Seeing `extern` declarations of the form `__start_<section_name` or `__stop_<section_name>`,
the linker will automatically place these symbols at the start and end respectively of
section `<section_name>`.

And should you want to compile and link multiple source files that all access the same custom
section `my_section` in a program, you can simply define symbols attributed to section
`my_section` in the several source files and the linker, with the default linker script,
with merge all the sections called `my_section` in the input object files into a single
output `my_section` in the program. (Just as it merges, e.g. all the `.text` sections
of the input object files into a single `.text` section of program). See:

```
$ cat foo.c
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int foo __attribute__((section("my_section"))) = 0xf00;

$ cat boo.c
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int boo __attribute__((section("my_section"))) = 0xb00;

$ cat main3.c
#include <stdio.h>

extern unsigned int foo;
extern unsigned int boo;

int main(){
    printf("foo=%x, boo=%x\n",foo,boo);
    return 0;
}

$ gcc -Wall -o prog main3.c foo.c boo.c
$ ./prog
foo=f00, boo=b00
```

and:

```
$ readelf -t prog | grep my_section
  [24] my_section
```

there is only one section, 24, called `my_section` in the program, which:

```
$ readelf -s prog | egrep '(foo|boo)'
    36: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS foo.c
    37: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS boo.c
    59: 0000000000004010     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 foo
    66: 0000000000004014     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 boo
```

contains the definitions of both `foo` and `boo`.